# Replace Match with Find and paste all found values into new rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in Sheet 2 that consists of some data. In column A there may be value: "Quota number XYZ". It may occur more than once, and it may not occur at all.

I would like to find all Quota Numbers and paste them in new rows in Sheet 1.

How the macro works:

I have list of numbers in column A in Sheet 1. External data is pasted to Sheet 2. Macro looks for "*Quota number:*" in Column A in Sheet 2, but since I use Match it returns only 1 value and copies it to column that is next to number in Sheet 1.

How it looks like:

```
Value Match  
45678 0110  
12345 0990   
34567 0550
```

I would like to find "*Quota number:*" in Sheet 2, and for first value found - copy it to next column. But for second and more values found I need to have extra row in Sheet 1. Example:

```
Value Match  
45678 0110  
12345 0990    
12345 0770   
34567 0550
```

The codes currently looks like that:

```vb
ws2.Activate 

For Each c In ws1.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
    If Not IsError(Application.Match("*Quota number:*", Range("A:A"), 0)) Then
        Quota = Application.Match("*Quota number:*", Range("A:A"), 0)
        QuotaVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(Quota, 1)

        ws1.Cells(c.Row, 2).Value = QuotaVal
    End If
Next c
```

I was trying to figure it out, but I have no idea how to make it so it adds new rows on 2nd and further matches, and how not to make the loop to loop itself (new row added so the new c appears).

Comment: I think you'll need to check out the `Find` method for multiple matches.

Comment: Does this need to be VBA? It looks like a [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) would work.

Comment: Macro scrapes tables and puts them to sheet2, after values are found, table is removed and new one is scraped - no way to vlookup this, especially when one "Value" can have multiples matches.

I am aware on Find function, but have no idea how to use it with adding new rows - since I am using "For each c in range", and I would like to add new rows to this range, I am afraid that my loop will go over and over the same, but added, numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an alternative way to do it, but I have faced some issues.

I've decided to find and copy results to another sheet, so the results are pasted in Sheet3 column 2, and colunm 1 for each result is filled with number from Sheet1 (the "Value" from original post").

It works great if I have only 1 value. I have 2 numbers in sheet1, data with "Quota numbers" in Sheet2, and results in Sheet3. I have many rows with dummy data in Sheet2, and only 5 "Quota numbers".

So, for each number in Shee1 it has to find "Quota number" in sheet2 and paste results to sheet3. If my "For" range in only 1 cell, it works great - returns me with 5 quota numbers. But if I change my range to "A1:A2", it should find the same data 2 times, so total 10 numbers should be found - but it somehow doesn't work like that and founds 7 numebrs.

How it looks like:

[Sheet1 - numbers that will be used to generate data in Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFEqL.png)

[Sheet2 - Generated data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9Lk1.png)

[Results when searching only for 1 cell in range (with the code quoted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4lf0.png)

[Results when searching only for 2 cells in range (with the code unquoted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ0Q1.png)

```
Sub GetData()

Dim x As Range

'For Each x In Sheets(1).Range("A1:A2")

With Worksheets(2).Range("A1:A500")

     Set c = .Find("Quota number*", LookIn:=xlValues)
     If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
           'Sheets(3).Cells(c.Row, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = x.Value
            Sheets(3).Cells(c.Row, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = c.Value
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        If c Is Nothing Then
            GoTo DoneFinding
        End If
        Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress
      End If
DoneFinding:

End With

'Next

End Sub
```

Comment: issue solved - there was a mistake in cells logic. Working part of the code:  
 Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1).Value = c.Value
            Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2).Value = x.Value